# Flutter Firestore Pagination (add/remove items)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, mobx

I'm struggling to get this done, after two days I decided to ask you guys for help.
I'm using Mobx as state management, the issue is related to adding/removing an item to/from the list, e.g. if I retrieve two queries of 5 items each, according to the limit and then remove an item from the first query the first item from the second query is duplicate and if I add a new item, the first item from the second query is hidden. I have also set a scrollListener to the ListView.builder to get the bottom of the list and call for more items.

Thanks in advance,

```
@override
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> teste(DocumentSnapshot lastDoc) {
    if (lastDoc == null) {
      return firestore.collection('teste')
      .orderBy('name')
      .limit(5)
      .snapshots();
    } else {
      return firestore.collection('teste')
      .orderBy('name')
      .limit(5)
      .startAfterDocument(lastDoc)
      .snapshots();
    }
  }

  @observable
  ObservableList<List<TesteModel>> allPagedResults = ObservableList<List<TesteModel>>();

  @observable
  ObservableList<TesteModel> listTeste = ObservableList<TesteModel>();

  @observable
  DocumentSnapshot lastDoc;

  @observable
  bool hasMoreItem;

  @action
  void teste() {
    var _currentRequestIndex = allPagedResults.length;
    
    primaryRepository.teste(lastDoc).listen((query) {
      if (query.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        var _query = query.docs.map((doc) => TesteModel.fromFirestore(doc))
        .toList();

        var _pageExists = _currentRequestIndex < allPagedResults.length;

        if (_pageExists) allPagedResults[_currentRequestIndex] = _query;
        else allPagedResults.add(_query);

        listTeste = allPagedResults.fold<List<TesteModel>>(<TesteModel>[],
          (initialValue, pageItems) => initialValue..addAll(pageItems)).asObservable();

        if (_currentRequestIndex == allPagedResults.length - 1) lastDoc = query.docs.last;
        
        hasMoreItem = _query.length == 5;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you're paginating and are showing two "page fulls" of data, you need to be listening to both streams - or to a single stream of double the page size. Otherwise you'll indeed run into overlap/gap issues. But of the listeners for both the first and second page remain active, they both should fire in such cases as you describe. If that is not happening for you, can you show the problem in a way we can also look at - for example, by printing the IDs and including the code and output in your question?

Comment: hi, I have already added the code, the output is just a list e.g. first query/page [1,2,3,4,5], when I retrieve the second query I'll have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and if I remove an item from the first query/page e.g the first item the output will be [2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10]. Sorry, I don't know if its clear.. thx

Answer (score 1):

Any luck with this issue?

For adding new items and having multiple pages you could do something like this:

```
if (allPagedResults.contains(allPagedResults[0].last) == false) {
   allPagedResults.last.add(allPagedResults[0].last);
   allPagedResults.last.remove(allPagedResults[0].first);
}
```